# How to send JSON data to my "vultr" server using URLRequest

Tags: swift

I want to use the URLSession to send a json data that store the detail information to the server bought from vultr. The url is the server ip address and I already set the username and password in the postParams and set the request's httpBody property. The problem is that I can't connect the server.

I thought it should be the problem that I fail to connect to the server. I just buy a server and do nothing to it. The server has a username and a password. I don't know whether I should first setup the server or if I can use it directly after finishing the purchase.

```swift
 private func sendData() {
        let url = URL(string: "https://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx")!
        var request = URLRequest(url: url)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        let postParams = "username=root&password=*****"
        let postData = postParams.data(using: .utf8)
        request.httpBody = postData
        let task = URLSession.shared.uploadTask(with: request, fromFile: AppDelegate.data.filename!) { data, response, error in
            if let error = error {
                print("error: \(error)")
                return
            }
            guard let response = response as? HTTPURLResponse, (200...299).contains(response.statusCode) else {
                print("server error")
                return
            }
            if let mimeType = response.mimeType, mimeType == "application/json", let data = data, let dataString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) {
                print("got data: \(dataString)")
            }

        }
        task.resume()
    }
```

The error message is shown as followed:

2019-09-07 21:02:46.880119+0800 HeadGaze[2241:445676] Task .<1> finished with error - code: -1004
error: Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1004 "Could not connect to the server." UserInfo={NSUnderlyingError=0x2807e0f30 {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1004 "(null)" UserInfo={_kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=61, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=1}}, NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://155.138.243.166/, NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://155.138.243.166/, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=1, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=61, NSLocalizedDescription=Could not connect to the server.}

Comment: Have you tried to connect to the server using a web browser?

Comment: Yes, I just try the https://155.138.243.166 and the connection is failed. I don't know whether I fail to set up the server.

Comment: Then it's not a programming issue so not much we can do about it.